# So, who should daemonize? The script or the caller?

Tags: daemon, process-monitoring

I'm always wondering who should do it.  In [Ruby](http://ruby-lang.org/), we have the [Daemons](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/) library which allows Ruby scripts to daemonize themselves.  And then, looking at [God](http://god.rubyforge.org/) (a process monitoring tool, similar to [monit](http://www.tildeslash.com/monit/)) page, I see that God can daemonize processes.

Any definitive answer out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably cannot get a definitive answer, as we generally end up with both: the process has the ability to daemonize itself, and the process monitor has the ability to daemonize its children.

Personally I prefer to have the process monitor or script do it, for a few reasons:
1. if the process monitor wishes to closely follow its children to restart them if they die, it can choose not to daemonize them. A SIGCHLD will be delivered to the monitor when one of its child processes exits. In embedded systems we do this a lot.
2. Typically when daemonizing, you also set the euid and egid. I prefer not to encode into every child process a knowledge of system-level policy like uids to use.
3. It allows re-use of the same application as either a command line tool or a daemon (I freely admit that this rarely happens in practice).

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is better for your script to do it.  I don't know your process monitoring tool there, but I would think users could potentially use an alternative tool, which means that having the script do it would be preferable.

If you can envision the script run in non-daemon fashion, I would add an option to the script to enable or disable daemonization.